# IE 8 crashes instead of opening debug dialog on encountering "_asm int 3;" in the dll code

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging

I wanted to set breakpoint in the dll code so I introduced the statement "_asm int 3;". IE is supposed to open a dialog box saying that an unexpected exception has occured, and whether to close or debug. But it simply cuts down the window. The dll is a _Debug version not _Release version.
 Another thing I noticed is that using the "debugger;" statement in the javascript code also causes the same behaviour - window dies without notice.
Why is this happening?

Comment: JIT debugging is a Visual Studio feature, not an IE feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JIT debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) might be disabled. In your Visual Studio options, under `Debugging > Just-In-Time`, check the `Native` and `Script` options.

As an aside, you should probably call [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of issuing `_asm int 3`. It's clearer that way.

Comment: So, was that a JIT configuration problem after all? :)

Comment: I don't have the Debugging menu in my Visual C++ 98. This help I found http://explodingcoder.com/blog/content/visual-studio-fail-how-not-debug-net-exception-handling tells to go to Tools menu, select "Import and Export Settings" for choosing Visual Studio Development Settings, but in my Tools menu I don't find any such item "Import and Export Settings". I also tried going to Tools->Customize->Category:Menus and selected "Debug" from the "Commands" list shown, and it only brings in 3 new menu items - Image, Layout and Query, for God's sake.  I had tried DebugBreak(), that also caused the crash.

Comment: You don't have a JIT-capable environment. If at all possible, install a more recent IDE, e.g. the free [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

Comment: One more thing is that it had breaked at the debug point and opened the visual studio for debuging, a couple of times in the past, and then all of a sudden it started crashing. Then someone suggested to try IE7, and after I downgraded to IE7, it worked for a couple of times, and then afterwards just started crashing the window without prompting. If I don't have a JIT capable environment, how could it have worked sometimes?

Comment: Well, you *did* have a JIT-capable environment before, but it's broken now :)

Comment: Not quite. It has just now started breaking and opening the Visual studio all of a sudden. One doesn't know when it will start crashing silently again.